# Accessing a parent's data in a child

Tags: java

**Situation**

Let's say I have a panel (or any other java object) which has some context information. Embedded in this panel are some other panels.

**Question**

Is there some mechanism to access the parent panel's context information without handing over the context in e. g. the constructor? If so, how would that work?

Basically instead of this:

```
    public class Context {
        public int someParameter;
    }

    public class ParentClass extends JPanel {

        Context context;

        public ParentClass() {

            context = new Context();

            setLayout( new FlowLayout());
            add( new ChildClass( context));

        }

    }

    public class ChildClass extends JPanel {

        Context context;

        public ChildClass( Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void perform() {
            int number = context.someParameter;
        }

    }
```

I more or less would like to have something like this, with @WireToParentPanel as a symbolic annotation:

```
    public class Context {
        public int someParameter;
    }

    public class ParentClass extends JPanel {

        Context context;

        public ParentClass() {

            context = new Context();

            setLayout( new FlowLayout());
            add( new ChildClass());

        }

    }

    public class ChildClass extends JPanel {

        @WireToParentPanel
        Context context;

        public void perform() {
            int number = context.someParameter;
        }

    }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can't you do this with normal dependency injection like the technique used in Spring framework?

Comment: I rather prefer not having a dependency on some 3rd party framework. I guessed it might be possible somehow with Java 8?

Comment: Why don't you declare `Context context` as protected in `ParentClass` and have `ChildClass` inherit from `ParentClass` - then you don't need to declare `context` in the child and it can simply manage the parent.

Comment: ChildClass is just some nested component, not a subclass of ParentClass. There can be multiple of these ChildClass objects in the ParentClass.

Comment: @Roland I think you might be trying to re-invent the wheel in that case. Spring and many other frameworks already offer a robust bean injection technique. If really want the implementation done on your own the best thing you could do would be to steal it from the best in business: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework

Comment: @shyam: Ok, thank you. I'll give it a try. I thought that with Java 8 the need for 3rd party frameworks would be obsolete for that case. I guess I was wrong.